# C++ Eigen: 'Options' : is not a member of 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>'

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

Whenever I try to create templated functions for Eigen, I get errors like this one:

error C2039: 'Options' : is not a member of 'Eigen::MatrixBase'

This error came from the following function

```
template<typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
void eig(const MatrixBase<Derived1> & A, MatrixBase<Derived2> & eigenvaluesBuff) {
    EigenSolver<MatrixBase<Derived1>> es(A, false);
    eigenvaluesBuff = es.eigenvalues().real().col(0);
}
```

The matrix, A, is a MatrixXd that was returned by a different function. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? If a function returns a MatrixXd, can you not pass that result directly into a templated function in Eigen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template parameter of `EigenSolver` needs to be an instantiation of the more specific [`Eigen::Matrix`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) template, not `Eigen::MatrixBase` (see the documentation [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html)).  So I would change your template function to

```
template<typename Scalar, int Rows, int Cols, int Options, int MaxRows, int MaxCols, typename Derived2>
void eig(const Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols, Options, MaxRows, MaxCols> & A, MatrixBase<Derived2> & eigenvaluesBuff) {
    typedef Matrix<Scalar, Rows, Cols, Options, MaxRows, MaxCols> MatrixType;
    EigenSolver<MatrixType> es(A, false);
    eigenvaluesBuff = es.eigenvalues().real().col(0);
}
```

You could also simplify the function to

```
template<typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
void eig(const MatrixBase<Derived1> & A, MatrixBase<Derived2> & eigenvaluesBuff) {
    eigenvaluesBuff = A.eigenvalues();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make all of the functions as similar to matlab as possible. In this case, that means renaming it to eig and later making the function return the eigenvalues directly, not in a buffer. Thanks for your explanation though - I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

To complete David's answer, let me add that you can get the Matrix type matching a given expression with PlainObjectType. So a more general solution would be:

```
template<typename Derived1, typename Derived2>
void eig(const MatrixBase<Derived1> & A, MatrixBase<Derived2> & eigenvaluesBuff) {
    EigenSolver<typename Derived1::PlainObjectType > es(A.derived(), false);
    eigenvaluesBuff = es.eigenvalues().real().col(0);
}
```